# Python skips my if statement when I type 0 as the user input even though it should (I think) generate a random number

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a script that gives a random number of abilities if the user writes 0 but now it just completely ignores my if statement and just doesn't print any abilities at all even though it works perfectly fine when you enter anything else

```
import random

def RandomizeAbilities():
    NumberOfAbilities = int(input("How many abilities do you want your character to have? (1-100, leave 0 for random) "))
    if NumberOfAbilities == "0":
        NumberOfAbilities == random.randint(0,101)
    GeneratedAbilities = 0
    while GeneratedAbilities < NumberOfAbilities:
        AbilitiesDictionary = open("Abilities.txt", "r")
        Abilities = AbilitiesDictionary.read()
        ListOfTiers = Abilities.split(",")
        RandomizedAbility = random.choice(ListOfTiers)
        print("Your character's Ability is: ", RandomizedAbility)
        GeneratedAbilities += 1
```

Abilites.txt:

```
Absolute Zero,Absorption,Abstract Existence
```

if you need the rest of the code it's available at https://github.com/Paloftzer/TSWCharCreator

Comment: To assign to a variable use a single equal sign, two equal signs are a test for equality.

Comment: You're converting the input to `int`, but comparing it to a string. That's guaranteed to be False.

Comment: @BilltheLizard Thanks, that fixed it, can't believe I missed that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are comparing an ***Integer*** to a ***String***, both are fundamentally **different data-types** and therefore the **if-statement** returns `False`.

Try this:

```
import random

def RandomizeAbilities():
    NumberOfAbilities = int(input("How many abilities do you want your character to have? (1-100, leave 0 for random) "))
    if NumberOfAbilities == 0: # changed to int '0' instead of '"0"'
        NumberOfAbilities = random.randint(0,101)
    GeneratedAbilities = 0
    while GeneratedAbilities < NumberOfAbilities:
        AbilitiesDictionary = open("Abilities.txt", "r")
        Abilities = AbilitiesDictionary.read()
        ListOfTiers = Abilities.split(",")
        RandomizedAbility = random.choice(ListOfTiers)
        print("Your character's Ability is: ", RandomizedAbility)
        GeneratedAbilities += 1
```

To get a **better grasp of the concept behind data-types**, I would strongly recommend to  read:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html

Comment: @TobiasHermann you're absolutely right, took care of it.